# Sort array in order of item frequency Java Please send full code

Tags: arrays

I want to sort an array and print the array elements on the count if 9 appears 4 times then 9 should print first, if 2 appears 3 times and 5 appears 4 times then 5 should print before 2.

Example input:

```
{1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,9,9,9,9}
```

Desired output:

```
{9,9,9,9,1,1,1,5,5,3,3,4}
```

Comment: input array= {1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,,9,9,9,9}
Want o/p={9,9,9,9,1,1,1,5,5,3,3,4}

Comment: You should edit your input and expected output into the question please. It might be helpful if you tell us what programming language you're working in (and tag the question with it), e.g. this would be fairly simple to do in C#'s LINQ with GroupBy and OrderBy.

Comment: But please note that this reads as an exercise or a homework question, and you're not going to learn if we just write code for you (nor are we likely to do so). Please clarify exactly what part of this you're stuck on so we can give you specific guidance so that you can solve this yourself.

Comment: Indeed. As @Rup points out you can use grouping and sorting. Just write a groupBy yourself. Or you can use reduce

Comment: "Please send full code" - we're not going to do your work for you. To do this you're going to have to 1) count the frequencies of each value, e.g. into a Map 2) sort these by decreasing frequency and by decreasing value, e.g. by making an ArrayList of the Map.Entry s and writing a comparator for these 3) iterate through the sorted list of Map.Entry objects and add each value the frequency number of times to a new array or list. Do you think you can do that?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like a reasonable excuse to play with Java 8 streams, so here you go!

```
static int[] orderByFrequencyDesc(int[] input) {
    return Stream.of(IntStream.of(input).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).entrySet())
            .flatMap(Set::stream).sorted((o1, o2) -> o2.getValue().equals(o1.getValue())
                    ? o2.getKey() - o1.getKey() : (int)(o2.getValue() - o1.getValue()))
            .flatMapToInt(e -> IntStream.generate(e::getKey).limit(e.getValue())).toArray();
}
```

Comment: New to java,But i will try.